# Is it possible to eat quietly in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In some multiplayer games it is necessary to hide from other players. On one occasion I had to eat food while hiding; the loud chewing sound alerted a player to my presence who then found and killed me.

Is there a way to eat quietly? If not to maintain stealth, just to have good table manners.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The only way would be a cake, the placement sound is much quieter and eating it makes no sound.

Otherwise only resource packs can disable eating sounds, but of course only for yourself.

Comment: Also, a cake can be eaten a few times and takes almost no time to eat (based on what I've seen). It's like if you were punching the cake to get a slice. it has the disadvantage that you have to place it somewhere. If you are hidding somewhere where you only have a 2x1 area, you will still have to resort to loud food.

Comment: Cake also provides almost no saturation and isn’t stackable, so is impractical to carry